# How do I get rid of all the previous 'merge masters' in my Pull Request on Github?

Tags: github

Whenever I make a pull request on Github, in the commit tree it shows tons of previous commits that were made starting 13 days ago. How do I get rid of all that?

My git flow is usually:

1. git pull master
2. git checkout -b "another branch"
3. git add
4. git commit -m "message"
5. git push origin master

[image: merge commits]

Comment: You can avoid these commits with the command `git rebase `. Otherwise, I can recommend the [post](https://arjanvandergaag.nl/blog/clarify-git-history-with-merge-commits.html) and the use of the command `git pull --rebase`.

Answer (score 0):

If, while checked out on `another branch`, you run `git rebase master`, `another branch` will essentially become the most recent `master` plus all the commits you have added to `another branch` since you created it.

I would recommend reading a short tutorial about rebasing if you haven't done it before.